# `dirname': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, bundler

I'm not sure if this is in cucumber really, but just in case some of you guys have a clue on how to fix this. Basically, my tests suddenly stopped working and when I checked, it showed this error:

```
C:/Vendor/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/rails3.rb:3 in 'dirname': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
```

Yes, I first rolled my eyes and just cursed Windows but I tried it on my Mac and I got the same:

```
/Users/eumir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@mygemset/gems/cucumber-rails-0.5.2/lib/cucumber/rails3.rb:3:in `dirname': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
```

Weird though, its in different cucumber rails versions, I googled and the first result shows it is bunder's fault(although I can't decipher what the gist is about...maybe just copy pasted stuff?) and weirdest of all, Cucumber IS running and I run into this problem while running `rspec spec`.

The 3 clues below point out that it's not cucumber's fault, but why does it blame cucumber? IF any of you can shed a clue as to why this is happening, you'll be saving me from a few more hours of pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aslak says in his reply:

http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/msg/803836e9f6e7f1be

I just needed to upgrade cucumber-rails. @Ewout did point me in the right direction too so he also deserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 20):

This was caused by how bundler attempts to "autorequire" gems. In 1.0, bundler tries the gem name (in this case "cucumber-rails") and smothers the error if the file isn't found (it isn't).

In bundler 1.1.1, bundler replaces instances of "-" with "/", resulting in it autorequiring "cucumber/rails" which results in the "accidental" loading described by Ewout.

To resolve, set `:require => false` in your gemfile.

(Note: `:require => false` doesn't mean that the gem is optional, just that Bundler shouldn't auto-require it)

Answer (score 8):

New cucumber-rails versions warn you about this problem. Cucumber-rails should be required from the env.rb file, and not before by bundler. To achieve that, put the `gem cucumber-rails` line in the group :test within your Gemfile.

Comment: this worked for me on an old version-locked project. good to know that bundler auto-loads your gems, especially if you have code like

`VAR = (something) unless defined? VAR`

in an old gem (as this project has)